# Discord.js: send() is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Here's the code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client()

client.on('ready', ()=>{
    console.log("Connected as "+client.user.tag)

    client.user.setActivity("the Universe", {type: 'WATCHING'})

    client.guilds.cache.forEach((guild)=>{
        console.log(guild.name)
        guild.channels.cache.forEach((channel)=>{
            console.log(` - ${channel.name} ${channel.type} ${channel.id} `)
        })
        // game-room-1 id: 774627995826520064
    })

    let gameRoom1 = client.channels.fetch('XXXX')
    gameRoom1.send("Hi @ARGØN");
})

client.login("TOKEN")
```

[image: See this]

`gameRoom1.send()` is giving `TypeError: gameRoom1.send is not a function`. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`client.channels.fetch('XXXX')` [returns a promise](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/ChannelManager?scrollTo=fetch) so you need resolve it first:

```js
client.on('ready', async ()=>{
    console.log("Connected as "+client.user.tag)

    client.user.setActivity("the Universe", {type: 'WATCHING'})

    client.guilds.cache.forEach((guild)=>{
        console.log(guild.name)
        guild.channels.cache.forEach((channel)=>{
            console.log(` - ${channel.name} ${channel.type} ${channel.id} `)
        })
        // game-room-1 id: 774627995826520064
    })

    let gameRoom1 = await client.channels.fetch('XXXX')
    gameRoom1.send("Hi @ARGØN");
})
```